# oracle query for merge to row into one

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with which showing in_time and out_time with gate number at separate row, but I wanted to show up this in one row, so I need to merge both rows into one here is result for this

```
   | EMPID |                IN_TIME |               OUT_TIME | IN_GATE | OUT_GATE |
   |-------|------------------------|------------------------|---------|----------|
   |   124 | 01-12-2019 08:49:35 AM |                        |       4 |          |
   |   124 |                        | 01-12-2019 06:53:03 PM |         |        5 |
   |   125 | 01-12-2019 07:49:35 AM |                        |       4 |          |
   |   125 |                        | 01-12-2019 05:53:03 PM |         |        5 |
```

Here what I expected

```
   | EMPID |                IN_TIME |               OUT_TIME | IN_GATE | OUT_GATE |
   |-------|------------------------|------------------------|---------|----------|
   |   124 | 01-12-2019 08:49:35 AM | 01-12-2019 06:53:03 PM |       4 |        5 |
   |   125 | 01-12-2019 07:49:35 AM | 01-12-2019 05:53:03 PM |       4 |        5 |
```

can you please give a solution for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to link `in` times with `out` times for each employee, something like the following should point you in the right direction:

See demo here: **[DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=71022a51bd3ab3c414723906c073fe87)**

```
select in_rec.empid, in_rec.in_time, out_rec.out_time, in_rec.in_gate, out_rec.out_gate 
from emp_att in_rec
inner join (
  select empid, in_time, (select min(out_time) 
                        from emp_att 
                        where empid = e.empid and out_time > e.in_time) out_time
  from emp_att e
  where in_time is not null
) in_to_out on in_to_out.empid = in_rec.empid 
               and in_to_out.in_time = in_rec.in_time
inner join emp_att out_rec on out_rec.empid = in_to_out.empid 
                              and out_rec.out_time = in_to_out.out_time
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try with `group by` and `aggregation`

**[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fba7ea/4)**

```
select empid, max(in_time) as in_time,max(out_time) as out_time,
       max(in_gate) as in_gate,max(out_Gate) as out_Gate
from tablename
group by empid
```

Comment: sorry I have not only one row

Comment: @mdkamrul, what do u mean by not only one row

Comment: @mdkamrul, have you tested my query   - it'll definitely work

Comment: sorry this only return one row, but I have multiple rows

Comment: This won't work if there are multiple entries per employee, it will only return one row per employee, even if attendance is recorded on 10 days.

Answer (score 0):

```
create table #temp (EMPID int,IN_TIME varchar(25),OUT_TIME varchar(25),IN_GATE 
int,OUT_GATE int)
insert into #temp values (124,'01-12-2019 08:49:35 AM',NULL,4,NULL)
insert into #temp values (124,NULL,'01-12-2019 06:53:03 PM',NULL,5)

select empid, max(in_time) as in_time,max(out_time) as out_time,
   max(in_gate) as in_gate,max(out_Gate) as out_Gate
   from #temp
   group by empid
drop table #temp
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see that `keep` clause is what you need here.

```
Select emp_id, 
       Min(in_time) as in_time,
       Max(out_time) as out_time,
       Min(in_gate) keep (dense_rank first order by in_time) as in_gate,
       Max(out_gate) keep (dense_rank last order by out_time) as out_gate
  From your_table
Group by emp_id, trunc(in_time)
```

Cheers!!